# How to make webpack resolve a common third package only one time

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

## situation:

1. I have three packages: A, B, and C.
2. All of those packages depends on package: D.
3. And I have a project which depends on package A, B, C , and D. And package D is a big package (size > 500KB)
4. When I run **webpack** in my project's root directory. Then the D package which is very big will be resolve 4 times, and make a very big bundle for my project!

## question:

Is there any way to make my project's bundle smaller ? I just want to transpile D package only once a time.

Comment: If this is happening, then it seems that packages A, B, and C are relying on different versions of package D.

Comment: you probably want this https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/

Comment: @Brad They are actually on same versions

Comment: @mikheevm However, I don't want to split my bundle

Comment: If your not splitting into multiple entry points, then this can't happen.  If you are on Windows however be careful of case, as `package` is not the same as `Package`.

Comment: @Keith I have the same problem after config the splitChunksPlugin

Comment: maybe try to do a `require('packageD')` in your application manually with the same version. 
looking at [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/require.resolve) require should include it, only once

Comment: thanks for everyone. I found the reason. It is because that I was using **npm link** for package A, B and C in my project. If I install those package in a normal approach, then every thing works as expected.